# Preserving order with PostgreSQL and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I'm running some elasticsearch queries and then taking those results and converting them into Active Record. Of course, order is not preserved.

I've had this working before but now I'm using `Ruby 2.3.1` an `Rails 5.1.1`.

I've tried all of the following solutions so I'm beginning to think this is some bug with this environment.

```
def self.find_ordered(ids)
  order_clause = "CASE id "
  ids.each_with_index do |id, index|
    order_clause << sanitize_sql_array(["WHEN ? THEN ? ", id, index])
  end
  order_clause << sanitize_sql_array(["ELSE ? END", ids.length])
  where(id: ids).order(order_clause)
end
```

Also:

```
def self.order_by_ids(ids)
  order_by = ["case"]
  ids.each_with_index.map do |id, index|
    order_by << "WHEN id='#{id}' THEN #{index}"
  end
  order_by << "end"
  order(order_by.join(" "))
end
```

And https://github.com/panorama-ed/order_as_specified gem:

```
Product.order_as_specified(id: [ids])
```

And https://github.com/khiav223577/find_with_order:

```
Product.find_with_order([ids])
```

All of these should work, but all default back to numerical order after being run. I'm running them in the console so no code could be being run after.

Edit: Example of request in console.

```
Product.where(id: [100,5,10]).order_by_ids([100,5,10]).pluck(:id)
  (127.0ms)  SELECT "products"."id" FROM "products" WHERE 
  "products"."id" IN (100, 5, 10) ORDER BY "products"."id" ASC, case 
 WHEN id='100' THEN 0 WHEN id='5' THEN 1 WHEN id='10' THEN 2 end
 => [5, 10, 100]
```

Comment: Have you looked at the actual SQL that is being sent to the database? BTW, there is no "default numerical order" in SQL, if you don't specify an ORDER BY clause then you get the rows back in whatever order the database feels like. And when you say `Product.order_as_specified(id: [ids])`, are you really doing things like `Product.order_as_specified(id: [1,11,6])` or `Product.order_as_specified(id: [[1,11,6]])`?

Comment: Product.order_as_specified(id: [[1,11,6]]) = correct

Comment: I posted an example of request in console.

Comment: Do you have a default scope or something? Where is `ORDER BY "products"."id" ASC` coming from?

Comment: Yes :( Someone else added it.. I see. Please make your answer a real answer so I can accept. Thanks! I was literally trying every solution and knew something else had to be up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the final SQL from your logs we see this:

```
ORDER BY "products"."id" ASC, ...
```

That suggests that something somewhere is doing:

```
order(:id)
```

The usual suspect when things mysteriously appear in your queries is a `default_scope` in your model. I tend to think that default scopes are evil, doubly so when they include an `order` call.

Go looking for a default scope and get rid of it. If you can't get rid of it (because something somewhere is depending on it), then kludge around it by throwing a `reorder('')` or `reorder(nil)` into your query before adding your `order by case ...` stuff or use `reorder('case ... end')` to replace whatever `ORDER BY` is there in one go; something like this:

```
def self.order_by_ids(ids)
  #... as before
  reorder(order_by.join(" "))
end

def self.order_by_ids(ids)
  #... as before
  reorder(nil).order(order_by.join(" "))
end

def self.order_by_ids(ids)
  #... as before
  reorder('').order(order_by.join(" "))
end

# etc.
```

You can also use `unscope(:order)` but `unscope` can do things you don't want so it is better to use `reorder` as it does exactly what you want and nothing else.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest solution to preserve order would be to order based on a field that doesn't change. In Rails, `created_at` would be such a field unless you're not using timestamps.

Comment: But the desired order is coming out of Elastic Search so at the PostgreSQL level they just have an array of `ids` and the desired order is implicit in the array. Hence all the `order by case ...` stuff.